# Compress repetition of 2 dimensional array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
var mycars = [['Ford', 'Fiesta', 'Manual', 'Rp. 160.000.000'],
            ['Ford', 'Fiesta', 'Manual', 'Rp. 163.000.000'],
            ['Ford', 'Fiesta', 'Automatic', 'Rp. 170.000.000'],
            ['Ford', 'Fiesta', 'Automatic', 'Rp. 175.000.000'],
            ['Ford', 'Fiesta', 'Automatic', 'Rp. 173.000.000'],
            ['Ford', 'Focus', 'Manual', 'Rp. 350.000.000'],
            ['Ford', 'Focus', 'Automatic', 'Rp. 400.000.000'],
            ['VW', 'Golf', 'Manual', 'Rp. 360.000.000'],
            ['VW', 'Golf', 'Manual', 'Rp. 365.000.000'],
            ['VW', 'Golf', 'Automatic', 'Rp. 390.000.000']];
```

Above is 2 dimensional array that has a lot of data repetition, that array need to simplify with provision as below:

- index data 0, must be full (no changes)
- data after index 0, if the value is the same as the previous index, change it to ''
- result data must remain in 2-dimensional array form

So the result will be as below

- index data 0, must be full (no changes)
- data after index 0, if the value is the same as the previous index, change it to ''
- result data must remain in 2-dimensional array form

So the result will show as below:

```
var mycars_compressed = [['Ford', 'Fiesta', 'Manual', 'Rp. 160.000.000'],
            ['', '', '', 'Rp. 163.000.000'],
            ['', '', 'Automatic', 'Rp. 170.000.000'],
            ...
            ['', '', 'Automatic', 'Rp. 400.000.000'],
            ['VW', 'Golf', 'Manual', 'Rp. 360.000.000'],
            ['', '', '', 'Rp. 365.000.000'],
            ...
];
```

And the result above could be decompressed again like the beginning.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira I think it's mostly one of the canned responses I got from the [AutoReviewComments](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoreviewcomments/bcfoamnigomkoaaiceppbbdlembpeejc) extension.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira If you're going to copy it, edit the name of the site to Stack Overflow (with a space between), as that's the correct spelling. :)

Comment: Back to the original question: it looks like you're trying to reinvent something like LZW, but with an added risk of catastrophic data loss if that array ever gets sorted while in its "compressed" form.  Maybe you'd be better off just enabling gzip on your web server instead, which would give you almost the same results without that risk?

Comment: I'm sorry for providing answer before he even tried to solve it by himself. Will keep in mind and not provide Data Structure solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a data structure question.

You gonna need 2 `for` loops.
Logic is simple will be using 2 more array one 2D and one 1D:

1. Assign first row of arr1 to arr2.
2. Leave first row and start loop with second one of arr1 `i=1`.
3. Set arr3 to empty array.
4. Start another loop for inner array `j=0`.
5. Check if `arr1[i][j] === arr[i-1][j]` **Yes** then push '' to `arr3.push('')`, if **Not** then push `arr1[i][j]` to `arr3.push(arr1[i][j])`.
6. Complete 2nd loop.
7. Assign `arr3` to `arr2.push(arr3)`.
8. Complete outer loop.

Here's working logic

`

```
var a1 = [], a2 = [];
let m = mycars.length
    n = mycars[0].length;

a1.push(mycars[0]);

for(let i = 1; i<m; i++) {
   a2 = [];

   for(let j =0; j<n; j++){

       if(mycars[i][j] == mycars[i-1][j]) {
           a2.push('');
       } else {
           a2.push(mycars[i][j]);
       }
   }
   //This is compressed array
   a1.push(a2);
}

var mycars_compressed = a1;
```

`

Comment: thanks for the answer how the logic if I want to decompressed again

Answer (score 0):

You could take a temporary array and check the value against the value of the tmeporary array at the same index and if the same take an empty string `''`, or take the value by storing that value to the temporary array.

For decompressing, you could take an assigment to the temporary array and check if the actual value is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), then take that value or take the value of the temporary array. Return that value.

```js
var data = [['Ford', 'Fiesta', 'Manual', 'Rp. 160.000.000'], ['Ford', 'Fiesta', 'Manual', 'Rp. 163.000.000'], ['Ford', 'Fiesta', 'Automatic', 'Rp. 170.000.000'], ['Ford', 'Fiesta', 'Automatic', 'Rp. 175.000.000'], ['Ford', 'Fiesta', 'Automatic', 'Rp. 173.000.000'], ['Ford', 'Focus', 'Manual', 'Rp. 350.000.000'], ['Ford', 'Focus', 'Automatic', 'Rp. 400.000.000'], ['VW', 'Golf', 'Manual', 'Rp. 360.000.000'], ['VW', 'Golf', 'Manual', 'Rp. 365.000.000'], ['VW', 'Golf', 'Automatic', 'Rp. 390.000.000']],
    compressed = data.map((t => a => a.map((v, i) => v === t[i]
        ? ''
        : t[i] = v
    ))([])),
    decompressed =data.map((t => a => a.map((v, i) => t[i] = v || t[i]))([]));

console.log(compressed);
console.log(decompressed);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  Is this not exactly what the OP was asking for?

Comment: thanks for the answer it works too how can I decompressed again